# NF > 0 checked two times on The UNiX Programming Environment

Tags: unix, awk

I'm reading The UNIX Programming Environment and in Section 4.4, about awk, there is this sample code:

```
    awk '
    FILENAME != prevfile {   # new file
        NR = 1               # reset line number
        prevfile = FILENAME
    }
    NF > 0 {
        if ($1 == lastword)
            printf "double %s, file %s, line %d\n",$1,FILENAME,NR
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
            if ($i == $(i-1))
                printf "double %s, file %s, line %d\n",$i,FILENAME,NR
        if (NF > 0)
            lastword = $NF
    }' $*
```

Why is NF > 0 tested inside the block which already had a NF > 0 as a pattern?

Comment: If you can achieve your goal without the `if` statement, then it must be a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem right. But it may have to do with maintaining compatibility with different versions of awk. If you have access to a system with awk, nawk, and gawk, you could try seeing if removing that `if` statement makes any difference for any of them.

Comment: It is possible to modify NF, but there's nothing doing that inside teh block, so I'd say it's an artifact from a previous version of the code that had different conditions in those two places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contained within the [errata](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/upe/errata.html) notes for this book:

```
Page 121, first program: test "if (NF > 0)" is unnecessary.
```

So it was a mistake made by the publisher and/or copy editor.

Answer (score 1):

NF > 0 is used to check if there are any fields in this line, because NF could be 0.

I give you an example:

```
awk '{print "hello";}' -
1
hello

hello
```

When I wrote "1" the block was executed (print "hello"), and I was executed again when I entered an empty line (second "hello")

If I change the code to:

```
awk 'NF > 0 {print "hello";}' -
1
hello
```

It does no show the second "hello" when the input is an empty line, because NF is 0.

Comment: I've asked why the check is done twice in the code, not why it is done at all.